# ¿Como puedo llamar una función en vez de un controlador en codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tengo el controlador principal **"inicio_c.php"**

Dentro tengo 2 funciones

```
public function index(){
$this->load->view('inicio');
}
public function logout(){
$this->session->sess_destroy();
redirect('/');
}
```

Pero cuando en mi ruta pongo **ip/web/logout** me sale el mensaje

```
404 Page Not Found
The page you requested was not found.
```

Reconoce el logout como si fuera un controlador... alguna forma de que vaya a la función? gracias!

Comment: Va a depender de como tengas configurado el htaccess, y por otro lado, debes llamar primero al controlador luego al metodo `inicio_c/logout` de esa manera si te va a funcionar, por otro lado tambien puedes configurar en el archivo routes el logout de salida `$route["logout"] = "inicio_c/logout"`

Comment: Depende de varias cosas, por lo general la URI se compone de `example.php/index.php/miController/miFunction/miParameter` en donde miController es el nombre de la clase, miFunction el nombre de la función y miParameter el parámetro.. Para que funcione sin el `.../index.php/...` tendrás que configurar el `.htaccess` y si querés hacer algo más complejo, utilizar el router.